# Cypress - SSO with Azure AD account

Tags: puppeteer, cypress

Is there a solution for cypress and single sign on for Azure AD? Azure AD doesn't seem to have an API that can be called with a login/password to login a user. There is an outstanding issue entered for this.

[Microsoft Azure Cypress Github issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1342)

I have tried using this [puppeteer](https://gist.github.com/saschwarz/b7f115ab6a7765ff5e45b9b9461cf895) solution, but I'm having the same issue as others. As soon as I use Cypress to navigate to my page, I get redirected back to the login.

Comment: Can you check the solution posted here helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342478/sample-cypress-script-to-bypass-sso

Comment: The accepted answer for the following question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64822167/6135684